# Adding external Jar to Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, kettle

I am working on Pentaho Kettle version 5.0.1. In one of my transformation  I am using javascript component where I am calling a method located in the JAR which I have copied to the lib folder of data-integration and everything is working fine in my local. But in my dev environment(I run it using kitchen) I don't have permission to copy my Jar file to the lib folder due to the restrictions on the server. Is there any other way using which I can supply the path of my custom Jar during run time so that the Kettle Job/Transformation can use it while being executed. Is there a way Kettle can pick the Jar location other than data-integration/lib?. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @codek : Please have a look. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers : Please help here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into kitchen.sh (and pan.sh). At some point the script starts adding stuff to the classpath. You can add more folders to the classpath there.

You still need permissions to edit the kitchen.sh file, though. If you can't do that, I suggest creating a copy of kitchen.sh you can write, in a separate location, and change the $BASEDIR folder to the actual PDI installation, so that kitchen can be located elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add the class path for kitchen/pan. Or redirect to the documentation on that.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't much documentation. but read the .sh file, you can find the classpath definitions around lines 15-25. It's quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If  you have permission you can put your jar in another directory and after you specify this directory in the launcher.properties which you find in data-integration\launcher. 
For exemple: if you put your jar in this directory: /export/home.
In launcher.properties: you will add this path and precisely libraries=../test:../lib:../libswt:../export/home